# natbib citation undefined, displays ? instead of reference title

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using overleaf with the inbuilt mendeley reference manager import and natbib to create my bibliography.

The main code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {title} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{2\textsuperscript{nd} Year Transfer Report}
\author{me}
\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\include{Sections/3_Literature Review}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

the problem is with the "Literature Review" section which looks like this

```
\section{Literature Review}
\justifying
BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH \cite{suman2014}
```

This citation appears as an error and natbib gives me the following errors

- Package natbib Warning: Citation `Suman2014' on page 6 undefined on
  input line 29.
- Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

The bibliography entry is like this

```
@article{Suman2014,
    title = {{Quantitative computational fluid dynamics analyses of particle deposition on a transonic axial compressor blade-part I: Particle zones impact}},
    year = {2014},
    journal = {Journal of Turbomachinery},
    author = {Suman, Alessio and Kurz, Rainer and Aldi, Nicola and Morini, Mirko and Brun, Klaus and Pinelli, Michele and Spina, Pier Ruggero},
    number = {2},
    pages = {1--14},
    volume = {137},
    doi = {10.1115/1.4028295},
    issn = {15288900}
}
```

If I use a different citation that worked in previous sections, the error does not appear. An example below:

```
@article{Kurz2012FoulingCompressors,
    title = {{Fouling mechanisms in axial compressors}},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {Journal of Engineering for Gas Turbines and Power},
    author = {Kurz, Rainer and Brun, Klaus},
    number = {3},
    volume = {134},
    doi = {10.1115/1.4004403},
    issn = {07424795}
}
```

I'm not sure its related, but I also have an error:

- White space in argument @input{Sections/3_Literature : Review.aux}

does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Somehow the issue is solved by referencing the same article again..! I also went through and took out all of the special characters in the bibliography produced by mendeley since some of the articles i referenced had them in it. I have left the question open since this seems like a "bodge" fix.

Comment: We can't test your code because it contains a number of `\input` and `\include` commands to files we don't have. If I remove those and just put in a single citation to Suman2014, it works fine for me. (Of course, like always, one has to re-rerun pdf/xe/latex twice after running bibtex.) Try to create a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks frabjous, I have edited the question to hopefully improve. When you say re-run, do you mean compiling the document?

Comment: Yes, I meant compile. In your example "Literature Review", `\cite(suman2014)` should be `\cite{suman2014}` with curly braces. Is that the problem? Seems to work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the question to include the curly braces, since they are there in my code but when I wrote it into stackexchange i defaulted back to normal braces :(

Comment: bibtex sometimes chokes on files with spaces in their names. You might try renaming `3_Literature Review.tex` to `3_Literature_Review` and see if that helps. Otherwise, the sample code works fine for me with TeXlive 2022. (I don't have an Overleaf account but it uses some version of TeXlive.)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed it! I will report it with overleaf though since this seems to be happening a lot and then randomly fixing itself...